# is it possible to read data from an OPEN Libreoffice Calc file?

Tags: python, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

The user opens an Calc .ODS file.

My program needs to read values from it "live", i.e. while it's open.

The reason for this is it's password protected, and there's no python API for password-protected worksheets.

pyexcel-ods reads a saved file, not an open one.

Answer (score 3):

Python-UNO is the built-in LO API. It offers two different ways to do this. The first is easier to set up although slower. To do this, start LibreOffice Calc listening on a socket. Then open a python prompt and enter `import uno`. The listening LO instance will be slower both for the GUI thread and for running the API commands from python.

The other way is to open LO Calc normally and then run python macros from inside, for example by going to *Tools -> Macros -> Run Macro*. Macros can also be run from events such as opening a document, or button or key presses. This is faster because python runs inside the same process as the application rather than needing to interact through a socket.

Either way, on Windows, use the python distribution that ships with LO, as that includes glue code to make it possible to import uno. A disadvantage of this is that you may not be able to install other python packages you might want, for example `lxml`. Linux integration is better in that the system wide python can load the UNO libraries, sometimes requiring a package to be installed first depending on your distro.

A tutorial is at http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html. The [APSO](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/apso-alternative-script-organizer-for-python) add-on helps run and organize the code.

Comment: Nice!  the docs say the port can be closed right after using it with --unaccept=all, so that should address performance. I'm checking it now.